# Dynamic index in elasticsearch with filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have installed filebeat on a server and monitoring the below log files

`C:\appl\dev\*\*\ms\*\*.log`

I have configured filebeat.yml as below

```
filebeat.inputs:
    - paths:
        - 'C:\appl\dev\*\*\ms\*\*.log'
      type: log
processors:
    - dissect:
        field: log.file.path
        tokenizer: "C:\\appl\\dev\\%{field1}\\%{field2}\\ms\\"
```

I have two requirements,
one is to get the events with two additional fields filed1 and field2 (this is working as per the above configuration).
The other one is to have the index name in elastic appended with this additional field (field1 or field2).

Currently index is a variable `(index: appname-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd})`
I need it to be `appname-field1-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}`

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me adding `output.elasticsearch` wasn't enough, had to add `setup.template` as well

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
  index: "appname-%{[field1]}-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

setup.template:
  name: 'appname'
  pattern: 'appname-*'
  enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but whatever change i do in this index the index pattern is not found in kibana. Only when I change setup: ilm:policy_name,the index is pattern is found. But here i am not able to update the additional field (field1) It shows error as failed to read ilm policy name

Comment: You also need to run [`./filebeat setup`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html#setup-command) prior to starting Filebeat.

Comment: @Ash interesting so what issue ur facing

Answer (score 1):

In your output configuration, you need to change the [`index` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es), like this:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
  index: "appname-%{[field1]}-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but whatever change i do in this index the index pattern is not found in kibana. Only when I change setup: ilm:policy_name,the index is pattern is found. But here i am not able to update the additional field (field1) It shows error as failed to read ilm policy name